# floats as indexers for MultiIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with multiindex in the form of (p,t) tuples, where p and t are floating point numbers. When I try to select a a certain value of p through slicing (`idx=IndexSlice`) I get the following error:

```
df.loc[idx[1.5,:]]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.0rc1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.py:496:
 FutureWarning: scalar indexers for index type MultiIndex should be integers and not floating point
```

I there a way around this issue?

Input DataFrame:

```
Pump  Time  
10.0  -10.60    0.000005
      -10.59    0.000031
      -10.58    0.000007
      -10.57   -0.000020
      -10.56   -0.000000
      -10.55    0.000005
      -10.54   -0.000013
      -10.53   -0.000049
      -10.52   -0.000031
      -10.51   -0.000041
      -10.50    0.000022
      -10.49   -0.000045
      -10.48   -0.000070
      -10.47   -0.000025
      -10.46    0.000002
...
-0.05  4.05      0.000610
       6.05      0.000443
       8.05      0.000318
       10.05     0.000380
       12.05    -0.000063
       14.05     0.000578
       16.05     0.000236
       18.05     0.000472
       20.05     0.001628
       40.05     0.000243
       60.05     0.000426
       80.05     0.000361
       100.05    0.000693
       120.05    0.000478
       140.05    0.000398
Name: p1Up, Length: 4400, dtype: float64
```

Desired output:

```
Pump  Time  
-0.05  4.05      0.000610
       6.05      0.000443
       8.05      0.000318
       10.05     0.000380
       12.05    -0.000063
       14.05     0.000578
       16.05     0.000236
       18.05     0.000472
       20.05     0.001628
       40.05     0.000243
       60.05     0.000426
       80.05     0.000361
       100.05    0.000693
       120.05    0.000478
       140.05    0.000398
```

df.info() throws:

```
MultiIndex: 4400 entries, (10.0, -10.6) to (-0.05, 140.05)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
p1Up    4400 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
```

Construction is by concatenation inside a for loop which iterates over different p values:

```
time = (extracted from a file)
lb = [(p,t) for t in time]
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(lb, names=['Pump','Time'])
col = ['p1Up','p1Down']
data = np.concatenate((p1up,p1down),axis=1)
# Build dataframes           
temp = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ind, columns=col)
df = pd.concat([df,temp])
```

Comment: if u post an example of the frame this would help; not sure what you think this type of indexing would do. you are presenting a scalar that is not an integer; it's unclear how to interpret this

Comment: Hey @Jeff! I have a series of time measurements, each for a different intensity, represented by p. I'm trying to get the measurement for intensity=1.5, which should return a dataframe with a time index. Does that help?

Comment: show your input frame and what the output you are wanting

Comment: show how you constructed and df.info()

Comment: Let's see if it's clearer now...

Comment: pls post your pandas version

Comment: the answer below is correct. you need to sortlevel() and then index as described. pls read all of the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some dummy data, this worked.

```
df.loc[idx[1.5,:], :]
```

As noted in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindexing-using-slicers), it's a good idea to specify the indexer for both axes to avoid ambiguity, although I'm not sure that's the issue here.

Comment: Hi @chrisb, when I try this way I get the following error:
`KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'`

Comment: this is the right answer. you need to fully specify the level indexers otherwise it's an error; you need to .sortlevel() otherwise it's also an error. these are all fully documented as described by the link above.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff. Yes sortlevel was the problem! Quick question though: How would you do to drop the 1.5 level (desired output without the 'Pump' level)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's too late, or syntax has changed, but `df.xs(1.5)` can do it, and it by default drops the selected level. I don't think you even need to lexsort it. But it only gets the data, cannot sets it.